# How to apply data-grouping to indicators in HighCharts highstocks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am using HighCharts engine to draw some stock-charts. Currently i use candlesticks and managed to change the candles time period by changing *plotOptions.dataGrouping* settings which are defined in react state:

```js
chageDataGrouping(){
    this.setState((prevState)=>({
        options:{
            ...prevState.options,
            plotOptions:{
                ...prevState.options.plotOptions,
                series:{
                    dataGrouping : {
                        //setting data grouping value to show each candle as a summary of 2 weeks candles
                        units: [['week', [1] ] ]
                    },
                    forced : true,
                    enabled : true,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}))
```

The above code works fine. The **Problem** is this : if there is an indicator present in the chart, changing the data-grouping setting in plotOptions, makes the indicator**s** disapear. By the way i am changing data grouping manually as user clicks on a button to select 'week','month',etc view.
Since i am using react and setting up chart options in react.state, it feels like i am some how re-redering the chart which makes the indicators disappear.
Any ideas? tnx.